# Method usage on ItemDataBound C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method to use on ItemDataBound;

```
 static void getPhoto() {
    Fonksiyonlar vt=new Fonksiyonlar();
    DataTable SeriFoto = vt.GetDataTable("select foto from seriFotograf where seriilanID=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ilan_id") + " and kapak=true" + " order by seriilanID desc");
    if (SeriFoto.Rows.Count < 1)
    {
        DataRow nullPhotoRow;
        nullPhotoRow = SeriFoto.NewRow();
        nullPhotoRow["foto"] = "0.png";
        SeriFoto.Rows.Add(nullPhotoRow);
    }
    Repeater rptReddedilenFoto = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptReddedilenFoto");
    rptReddedilenFoto.DataSource = SeriFoto;
    rptReddedilenFoto.DataBind();
}
```

But i get an error:

> The name 'e' does not exist in the current context

These codes running normally but it doesn't in method.

Comment: Is _e_ the argument passed to the event handler that calls this method?

Comment: What web-control are you using? A `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest, pass the `DataGridItem` to this method (or `GridViewRow` if it's a GridView):

```
static void getPhoto(DataGridItem item) {
    DataRowView view = (DataRowView) item.DataItem;
    Fonksiyonlar vt=new Fonksiyonlar();
    DataTable SeriFoto = vt.GetDataTable("select foto from seriFotograf where seriilanID=" + view["ilan_id"] + " and kapak=true" + " order by seriilanID desc");
    if (SeriFoto.Rows.Count < 1)
    {
        DataRow nullPhotoRow = SeriFoto.NewRow();
        nullPhotoRow["foto"] = "0.png";
        SeriFoto.Rows.Add(nullPhotoRow);
    }
    Repeater rptReddedilenFoto = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptReddedilenFoto");
    rptReddedilenFoto.DataSource = SeriFoto;
    rptReddedilenFoto.DataBind();
}
```